# JavaFX: Why are there two different styles?

Tags: java, versions, netbeans-7, javafx-2

I am learning JavaFX. I'm adding it to a Java Desktop App and I'm doing this using Netbeans 7. I've been searching the internet for JavaFX examples for whatever I want to do (embed in swing, set background, add gradient, incorporate animation...). I am finding two JavaFX styles.

- 1st Example: http://download.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/visual_effects/jfxpub-visual_effects.htm
- 2nd Example: http://javafx.com/samples/MediaBox/

I also found this http://netbeans.org/features/javafx/composer.html which says JavaFX support is currently not available in NetBeans IDE 7.0. And the screen shot is handling an FX Project which I don't have a choice to make in my Netbeans 7. I do have sample FX projects that I can make but these are really Java projects with FX in it (the 1st style of FX).

My guess is that JavaFX has been somewhat redesigned in the latest version, JavaFX 2. The 2nd example being the older style and the 1st being the newer. It seems to me that the 1st example is more like an addition to Java instead of a separate language.

Did I guess right? What's up with the two styles of FX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NetBeans JavaFX Composer is a tool that create CustomNodes with JavaFX components, but works with JavaFX 1.3.

NetBeans 7.0 has a JavaFX plug-in, but to version 2.0 (actually in beta).

JavaFX 1.3 is a DSL script language that runs over JVM and JavaFX 2.0 returns to be a Java API. They are totally differents, but conserving same Classes and ideas (CSS style, visual effects, etc).